# How can I connect switches to function the way I want?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

[image: Switch Box 1]
[image: Switch Box 2]
[image: Swithc Box 3]
[image: Switch Box 4]

This wiring is a disaster...

There are 4 switches in total and 3 lights. Depending on which switch is on, a different combination of lights turn on/off. 0 means switch is "off" and 1 means switch is "on". Order of switches is numerical 1,2,3,4. and results shows which light goes on. i.e: 0100 1st switch off, 2nd on, 3rd and 4th switch off.

0000 No Lights On
0100 Light #1 On
0010 Light #2 On
0001 Light #3 On
0110 Light #1 On (Light #2 should be on)
0011 Light #2 and #3 On
0111 Light #1 On (Lights #2 & #3 should be on)
0101 Light #1 On (Light #3 should be on)
1010 Light #2 On
1001 Light #3 On
1011 Light #2 and #3 On
1101 None Turn On (Lights #1,3 should be on)
1110 None Turn On (Light #1 & #2 Should be on
1100 None Turn On (Light #1 Should be on)
1000 None Turn On
1111 None Turn On (Lights #1,2,3 should be on)

I think I need to create a constant current with Switch #1, but when switch 1 and 2 are both "on" no lights turn on.

There are 4 Boxes in Total.

If all worked properly - I'd like Switch 1 and Switch 2 to be 3-ways turning off light 1, Switch 3 to be single pole switching off light 2, and Switch 4 to be single pole switching off light 3.

I have pictures of each box without the Switches connected that I can send along.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many locations (boxes) are these switches scattered across?

Comment: Also, are there any switch configurations where lights are on that should *not* be on?

Comment: What should be the effect of switch #1? According to your "should be"'s it should do nothing.

Comment: Can you include a wiring diagram, that to the best of your knowledge shows how all the switches and lights are wired? Also, could you indicate which switches are single pole and which are 3-way?

Comment: @brenth: You requirements seem doable. I have an abstract circuit diagram ready to go when this question is re-opened. - If you can diagram or accurately describe the relative positions of the switches and lights, and where the cables already run between them, I can post a practical wiring diagram also.

Comment: Which order are the pictures in?

Comment: Can you access the wiring in the boxes with the lights? Do you know how to do a continuity test?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I can't do a continuity test because they boxes are about 8 feet away from each other.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Top left is 1 Top right is 2 Lower left is 3 Lower right is 4

Comment: @brenth: There are two ways to do a continuity test on nodes that are more than a few feet apart. One obvious way is to use a long wire. I suggest a long extension cord with a pigtail shoved into one of the female end slots, and another pigtail wrapped around the corresponding male end prong.

Comment: @brenth: There are two ways to do a continuity test on nodes that are more than a few feet apart. One way is to test two wires at once: twist two wires together at one box and test for continuity between two wires at the other box. When you have done enough combinations the single wire continuities will emerge.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an abstract wiring diagram for the circuit you want, assuming the cable from light 1 runs to switch 1:

[image: abstract only, needs relative locations and cables]

Note the three-wire cable running between switch 1 and switch 2.

A practical wiring diagram first requires more information about the relative positions of the boxes and lights, and the cables already running between them.

Comment: Looks close- only thing I'm wondering is if that fixes below:


0110 Light #1 On (Light #2 should be on- is not)
0111 Light #1 On (Lights #2 & #3 should be on- are not)
0101 Light #1 On (Light #3 should be on)

Thanks

Comment: The switch settings in the diagram represent 0000. - I'll amend the diagram.